# RewriteCond param sharing multiple RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have three sites, sharing the same code

abc-local.org, abc-dev.org, abc.org

Want to redirect few URLs to a subdomain location on the site

```
    # Redirect Handles
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.abc(.*).org [NC]
    RewriteRule ^test1$ http://admin.abc%2.org/test1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^test2$ http://admin.abc%2.org/test2 [L]
```

The first Rule gets the value of %2, the second one does not !

Is there a way i can accomplish this without having to write a separate condition for each rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just 1 rule for multiple uris

```
    # Redirect Handles
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.abc(.*).org [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(test1|test2|test3)$ http://admin.abc%2.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```